# How do you find the size/rect of a uiimage?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, border

I have a UIImageView that has a UIImage (obviously), and I want to get the dimensions of the UIImage so that I can draw a border with rounded edges for just the UIImage (not the entire UIImageView).  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImage has a [-size](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW21) property.